# In AngularJS, how do you make a button appear only when the mouse is over a specific area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So, I have a form, with an accordion group header. It is the first thing you see before you expand the accordion group to view the form information on the inside. Currently, I have a button that is actually on the header, which makes it look tremendously cluttered, so I would like to have a button that pops to the side of the header when my mouse is over it. The endpoint overall, is to have a button that shifts over the entire header, which seems doable if I place it outside the right divs. I am unsure where I should use ng-show or ng-mouseover or etc. The button should still be within the accordion group headers range so it doesn't disappear before I can click on it. Is there a way to do something like this? This is what I currently have:

```
 <accordion-heading>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  {{animal.name | uppercase}}
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>{{animal.animal_type}}</td>
              <td>{{animal.lifespan}}</td>
              <td>{{animal.vertebrae}}</td>
              <td ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();  $event.preventDefault(); disableAppointment(animal);" class="">
                <i class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-remove':animal.apt_disabled,'glyphicon glyphicon-ok':!animal.apt_disabled }">
                </i>
              </td>
              <td ng-show="true"  ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" class="">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" ng-href="#/owners/{{animal.id}}" target="_blank"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"/></a>
              </td>
              <td ng-show="true"  ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" class="">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" ng-href="vets/{{animal.id}}" target="_blank"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"/></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </accordion-heading>
```

As you can see, I put 3 buttons on the header. The last two buttons, I do not actually want on it. I would rather have them pop up to the left of the header (and possibly shift it over) whenever someone hovers over it.

The closest thing I can find to what I want is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) but I've like it to be buttons and to the left.

Comment: can probably do this with basic css `:hover` rule. Not really clear what you are looking for...a live demo would help

Comment: The closest thing I can find to what I want is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) but I've like it to be buttons and to the left.

Comment: That's way too much code.  Could you delete some of that and just show so the minimum that is relevant to the question?  People will help you more then.

Comment: Not sure what is your exact ask but have a look at ng-mouseover